# Rearranging list containing dates in chronological order

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list:

```
A=['4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '4/21/2015', '4/21/2015']
```

Is there any Python code to arrange it in a chronological order?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
from datetime import datetime
A=['4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '4/21/2015', '4/21/2015']
FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y'
# create a list of sorted datetime objects
sorted_dates = sorted([datetime.strptime(d, FORMAT) for d in A])
```

Comment: Probably better using the `key` keyword argument:
`dates = sorted(A, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, FORMAT))`
This will result in a sorted list of the original strings and not `datetime` objects.

Comment: @tmr232 depends on the use case, I'd assume he is going to use them later... But thanks for the comment - added indication of what the result is in the code.